# Will Google Maps V3 always draw the same route?

Tags: google-maps

I have a route with an origin, a destination, and 0 or more waypoints. Will Google calculate the route in the same way every time? If for example, I will save the coordinates of all the points in the database, and I want to redraw it later, is it guaranteed that the map will look the same as when the points were first created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

Maps change over time as new roads are built, and Google is constantly [updating their mapping data](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/maps/thread?tid=4a63570fe66cb0e1&hl=en) to match.

Also, Google permits users to [edit routes and suggest corrections](http://www.google.com/mapmaker) to driving directions, which they take into account for future calculations.

Also, Google makes changes and improvements to their mapping algorithms from time to time, and they are not guaranteed to stick to the same algorithm in the future.

Comment: Is there a way I could save the map in the exact format it is and view it later?

Comment: Without knowing more about your problem, I would suggest getting the path for the driving directions, then using it with the [Google Static Maps API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/staticmaps/) to generate a static image with that path and thumbtacks.  You could then save the image.  Note: I have no idea whether the usage rules actually permit you to save an image from the static maps API--you might want to double check that this is allowed if you go this route.